#  Dynamically changing localization in VS2010 setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, localization

I would like to know how to change localization in VS2008 setup project dynamically. Scenario is like if operating system's langauge is french and user clicks on setup.exe, all screens should come in french and same for English langauge. I have created Setup project by keeping Localization property to English. It shows me all screens in English. Now If I changed Localization property to French, it shows me all screens in French. But I want it dynamically and it should consider machine langauge and display accordigly.